# Keep new html val of an element if the user presses enter or clicks outside

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent, keyboard-events

I'm trying to find a way with the following snippet to put the `.text(newContent)` value into the edited cell when the user clicks somewhere else out of the `<input>`.

For now, it only works when the user presses Enter on its keyboard. I've tryed adding a `e.type == "click"` or `e.which == 1` into the keypress function, but it can't work because it is an event on the `<td>` cell.

Is there a way to remove the `<input>` markup and to keep the user's values when they click outside of the td ?

```js
$(function () {
  
  $(".td").click(function () {
      
    var content = $(this).text();
  
 if ( $(this).text() == '...' ) {
  $(this).html('<input type="text" value="" size="8" />');
 } else {
  $(this).html('<input type="text" value="' + content + '" size="8" />');
 }
      
    $(this).children().first().focus();
 
    $(this).children().first().keypress(function (e) {
      if ( e.which == 13 ) {
        if ( $(this).val() == '' ) {
    var newContent = '...'
    $(this).parent().text(newContent);
     } else {
    var newContent = $(this).val();
    $(this).parent().text(newContent);
  }
      }
    });
      
  });
 
});
```

```css
#table td {
 width: 50px;
 border:1px solid #c0c0c0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="table">
  <tr>
    <td class="td" data-res="1">...</td>
 <td class="td" data-res="2">...</td>
 <td class="td" data-res="3">...</td>
 <td class="td" data-res="4">...</td>
 <td class="td" data-res="5">...</td>
 <td class="td" data-res="6">...</td>
 <td class="td" data-res="7">...</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: For starters you are attaching key event handlers inside a click event handler, *and never detaching them*. That means they will start firing multiple times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original had a few problem (nesting handlers is never a good idea as you get multiple events occurring). I did a complete re-write for you below using delegated handlers.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/ckk4ab3x/

This uses delegated event handlers to allow for dynamically created controls. It also targets the `focusout` event which is what you get when you leave the input.

```
$(function () {
    // Use a delegated event handler as the inputs are dynamic
    $('#table').on('focusout', 'td input', function () {
        var $input = $(this);
        var $td = $input.closest('td');
        var content = $input.val();
        $td.html(content == "" ? "..." : content);
    }).on('click', 'td', function () {
        var $td = $(this)
        var content = $td.text();
        if (content == '...') {
            content = "";
        }
        $td.html('<input type="text" value="' + content + '" size="8" />');
        // Focus on the new input
        $('input:first', $td).focus();
    });
});
```